# How to calculate time difference between specific row values in dataframe using python?

Tags: python, pandas, time

The df looks like below:

```
Time                    A 

2019-05-18 01:15:28     7
2019-05-18 01:28:11     7
2019-05-18 01:36:36     12
2019-05-18 01:39:47     12
2019-05-18 01:53:32     12
2019-05-18 02:05:37     7
```

I understand how to calculate consecutive row time difference. But I want to calculate the time difference whenever the Value in A is 7 to 12.

Expected output:

```
Time                    A   Time_difference

2019-05-18 01:15:28     7   0
2019-05-18 01:28:11     7   0
2019-05-18 01:36:36     12  00:21:08
2019-05-18 01:39:47     12  0
2019-05-18 01:53:32     12  0
2019-05-18 02:05:37     12  0
```

Comment: Is it a specific calculation that you need, or is there any rule regarding what rows to substract? Generally speaking, there is the `timedelta` object for time calculations.

Comment: yes specific rule, like the  window time between the occurence of 7 to 12 in column A.

Comment: there is possible multiple 7 or 12 value between `7` and `12` ?

Comment: yes. But the window will be between the first 7 to the first 12. Example: [7,4,7,7,12] 7 to 12 is the focus.

Comment: What return `df[df['A'].isin([7, 12])]` in real data?

Comment: It returns  series of [12,12,12,12,12]

Comment: Can you add more `7` and `12` values for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I think also if more consecutive `7` or `12` or both.

Comment: I did it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample:

```
times = [
    '2019-05-18 01:15:28',
    '2019-05-18 01:28:11',
    '2019-05-18 01:36:36',
    '2019-05-18 01:39:47',
    '2019-05-18 01:53:32',
    '2019-05-18 02:05:37'
]

a = [7, 7, 12, 7, 12, 7]

df = pd.DataFrame({'times': pd.to_datetime(times), 'A':a})
print (df)
                times   A
0 2019-05-18 01:15:28   7
1 2019-05-18 01:28:11   7
2 2019-05-18 01:36:36  12
3 2019-05-18 01:39:47   7
4 2019-05-18 01:53:32  12
5 2019-05-18 02:05:37   7
```

First create default index and filter rows with `7` and `12` only:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df[df['A'].isin([7, 12])]
```

Then get first consecutive values in rows with compare with shifted values:

```
df1 = df1[df1['A'].ne(df1['A'].shift())]
print (df1)
                times   A
0 2019-05-18 01:15:28   7
2 2019-05-18 01:36:36  12
3 2019-05-18 01:39:47   7
4 2019-05-18 01:53:32  12
5 2019-05-18 02:05:37   7
```

Then filter `7` with next `12` rows:

```
m1 = df1['A'].eq(7) & df1['A'].shift(-1).eq(12)
m2 = df1['A'].eq(12) & df1['A'].shift().eq(7)

df2 = df1[m1 | m2]
print (df2)
                times   A
0 2019-05-18 01:15:28   7
2 2019-05-18 01:36:36  12
3 2019-05-18 01:39:47   7
4 2019-05-18 01:53:32  12
```

Get datetimes with pair and unpairs rows:

```
out7 = df2.iloc[::2]
out12 = df2.iloc[1::2]
```

And last subtract:

```
df['Time_difference'] = out12['times'] - out7['times'].to_numpy()
df['Time_difference'] = df['Time_difference'].fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))
print (df)
                times   A Time_difference
0 2019-05-18 01:15:28   7        00:00:00
1 2019-05-18 01:28:11   7        00:00:00
2 2019-05-18 01:36:36  12        00:21:08
3 2019-05-18 01:39:47   7        00:00:00
4 2019-05-18 01:53:32  12        00:13:45
5 2019-05-18 02:05:37   7        00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can isolate any values in dataframes using `loc`. What gets returned is a Series, which can be indexed like a list. Use `[0]` to get the first occurrence in the Series.

```
times = [
    '2019-05-18 01:15:28',
    '2019-05-18 01:28:11',
    '2019-05-18 01:36:36',
    '2019-05-18 01:39:47',
    '2019-05-18 01:53:32',
    '2019-05-18 02:05:37'
]

a = [9, 7, 7, 5, 12, 12]

df = pd.DataFrame({'times':times, 'a':a})
df.times = pd.to_datetime(df['times'])
pd.Timedelta(df.loc[df.a == 12, 'times'].values[0] - df.loc[df.a == 7, 'times'].values[0])
```

`Timedelta('0 days 00:25:21')`

Or we can break that code apart for readability's sake and do the calculations on new variables:

```
times = [
    '2019-05-18 01:15:28',
    '2019-05-18 01:28:11',
    '2019-05-18 01:36:36',
    '2019-05-18 01:39:47',
    '2019-05-18 01:53:32',
    '2019-05-18 02:05:37'
]

a = [9, 7, 7, 5, 12, 12]

df = pd.DataFrame({'times':times, 'a':a})
df.times = pd.to_datetime(df['times'])
end = df.loc[df.a == 12, 'times'].values[0]
start = df.loc[df.a == 7, 'times'].values[0]
pd.Timedelta(end - start)
```

`Timedelta('0 days 00:25:21')`

Comment: Thank you! But it doesnot iterate through the dataframe to find another window of 7 to 12.  Like i put in the expected output, whenever there is a window 7 to 12 in the dataframe the difference should be calculated. I will tweak a little more on your logic and check...

Comment: I don't think that's what your expected output reflects. Wouldn't there be another time difference if you want it to keep going? In one comment you specifically said you want the first occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**:

- (df["A"] == 7).cumsum() separates rows to each 7
- for each group of 7, if there is 12 the substract the 1st row with 12 from 1st row of group
- If not pass value of 1st row of group to next group until 12 is found

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)
date_range = pd.date_range("25-9-2019", "27-9-2019", freq="3H")
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':date_range, 'A':np.random.choice([5,7,12], len(date_range))})

df["Seven"] = (df["A"] == 7).cumsum()

# display(df)
pass_to_next_group = {"val": None}
def diff(group):
    group["Diff"]=0
    loc = group.index[group["A"]==12]

    time_a = pass_to_next_group["val"] if pass_to_next_group["val"] else group["Time"].iloc[0]
    pass_to_next_group["val"] = None

    if group.name>0 and len(loc)>0:           
        group.loc[loc[0],"Diff"] =  time_a-group.loc[loc[0],"Time"]
    else:
        pass_to_next_group["val"] = time_a

    return group


df.groupby("Seven").apply(diff)
```